# Firefox not listing all audio output devices

Tags: security, firefox, audio, output, mediadevices

I know there are nearly identical issues here on SO but none of those solutions worked for me. The problem is, that `enumerateDevices()` only lists some output devices. I have built-in speakers (Realtek chipset) and a Jabra 410. The built-in speakers are never listed. But Jabra is listed (when connected). This is what I tried:

- Set `setSinkId.enabled` to true on about:config page
- Called `getUserMediad({audio: true, video: false})` before
- Tried to check permissions with: `navigator.permissions.query({ name: "speaker-selection" })`, but it looks like FF does not know this API
- Tried the solution in this post: [WebRTC: Firefox does not detect any output devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41569241/webrtc-firefox-does-not-detect-any-output-devices)

Would be great if someone could help, thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue. Firefox only lists devices that have a corresponding/associated microphone, so headsets work cause they have a mic/speaker (even if one is disabled and not the other), but speakers on their own are not listed in enumerateDevices.

If I call navigator.mediaDevices.selectAudioOutput in Firefox (after user interaction) a dialog popups up that lets me allow permission to the speaker.

Clearly a bug in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I raised a bug on Bugzilla about this and they regard this as an enhancement not a defect...
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1868750

Comment: Thanks Simon, that's a good hint! Indeed it sounds strange that they treat it as an enhancement. But anyway, at least they take care of it.